# Logging into new user shows old user in left sidebar on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, android-app

I logged out of my account so that a friend could log into his, and it worked. However, when I tried to go to the left sidebar and find the post that he wanted to edit, it still showed my user!

The inbox and feed still showed for the correct user, and when he edited his post it still went through with the correct user, but for some reason it still showed me on the left sidebar.

I'm using a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3.

Comment: I was that friend :)  I think it can easily be fixed by clearing **web cache** or logging out **online**

Comment: @ManofSnow "clearing web cache"? That makes no sense. And logging out online would not affect the app in any way...

Comment: It makes sense, usually I cannot log out of my account fully unless I **clear cookies.**

Comment: @ManofSnow ...it did log out fully. And it's an Android app... I have a feeling you have no idea what you're talking about :/

Comment: Then it's obviously a problem with the app :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun one. I had noticed it earlier but thought it was just due to the weird state our dev-site is in right now (since I only have multiple accounts on there).

What happens when you log out:

- Our local cache of your user information (saved in a local SQLite database) is removed
- Your access token (saved in a [SharedPreferences XML file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)) is removed.

The one I was missing? The instance of the local cache of your user information saved in our application's [base singleton class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

That one is now also wiped upon a log-out so no information of the user persists after they log out.

This will be in version 0.1.82 coming out around midnight UTC.